# regular expression to find: 4.55$, 5$, $45, $7.86 

Tags: c#, regex

What will be the regular expression to fined out 4.55$, 5$, $45, $7.86 in a string?

I used `@"(?<=\$)\d+(\.\d+)?"` but it only finds `$45`, `$7.86`.

Comment: I used @"(?<=\$)\d+(\.\d+)?" but its find only $45, $7.86

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work fine:

```
@"((?<=\$)\d+(\.\d+)?)|(\d+(\.\d+)?(?=\$))"
```

Example of code:

```
string source = "4.55$, 5$, $45, $7.86";
string reg = @"((?<=\$)\d+(\.\d+)?)|(\d+(\.\d+)?(?=\$))";
MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(source, reg);
foreach (Match match in collection)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit clumsy but here's another expression (with a bit of explanatory code) that might work for you:

```
string strRegex = @"\$(?<Amount>\d[.0-9]*)|(?<Amount>\d[.0-9]*)\$";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex);
string strTargetString = @"4.55$, 5$, $45, $7.86 ";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
    if (myMatch.Success)
    {
        //Capture the amount
        var amount = myMatch.Groups["Amount"].Value;
    }
}
```

Practically, what it does is to define an alternating way of matching the *$* at the begining or at the end of the amount.

I've tested this using [RegexHero](http://regexhero.net/tester/).

Answer (score -1):

I would use something like the following expression 'Globaly' within the string

```
string expression = @"(\$\d(\.\d*)?|\d(\.\d*)?\$)";
```

Comment: Don't forget to escape the dot.

Answer (score -4):

> What will be the regular expression to fined out 4.55$, 5$, $45, $7.86 in a string?

To find `4.55$, 5$, $45, $7.86` you can use `4.55\$, 5\$, \$45, \$7.86`.

**EDIT** Some commentators are worried that people will use this without understanding. I am providing an example, such that understanding can occur.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string search = @"The quick brown fox jumped over 4.55$, 5$, $45, $7.86";
        string regex = @"4.55\$, 5\$, \$45, \$7.86";

        Console.WriteLine("Searched and the result was... {0}!", Regex.IsMatch(search, regex));
    }
}
```

The output is `Searched and the result was... True!`.

Comment: I think that the amounts could be arbitrary. Hardcoding them in the regular expression is unlikely what the OP needs.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov The OP uses the word `fined`. Fines are usually fixed amounts.

Comment: @ta.speot.is, I think the OP used the word `fined out` when he actually meant `find out`.

Comment: Either way, if he's asking to "find out 4.55$, 5$, $45, $7.86 in a string?" my answer fits the bill perfectly. You guys can upvote me now.

Comment: @ta.speot.is, I normally upvote answers that put themselves into the context of the OP, not just blindly and literary answering the question. So personally I won't upvote your answer.

Comment: Successful troll is successful

Comment: @DanielMay Finally, someone that appreciates the correctness of my answer!

Comment: I think it is okay to have a laugh sometimes, but you have to think about how this site is used. Someone may come along and use your example. Are you _that_ intent on trolling?

Comment: @jesus.tesh I have an example so everybody can see how this works